# Passing file or stdin to boost process child ambiguously

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-process

I am trying to write a boost::process-based program that is able ambiguously redirect input, output and error streams based on whether to not a file to redirect them into is defined, but I'm struggling to figure out how to approach it:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main(){
  std::string in;
  std::string out("out.txt");

  namespace bp = boost::process;

  bp::child c(bp::exe("test.exe"), bp::std_in < (in.empty() ? stdin : in),  bp::std_out > (out.empty() ? stdout : out)); // error

  return 0;
}
```

The ternary operator won't work cause the types are incompatible, but I don't know how to achieve this. I explored boost::variant and boost::any but to no avail.

Comment: The code is merely an example of concept, not my actual code. I fixed the missing parenthesis, though I do believe my question is valid and reasonable

Comment: May I suggest dropping the word "Obviously"? That word rarely adds anything to a question, and it often -- not in this case, but often -- is used to slip misinformation into a question. Plus, if you don't call this fact "obvious", you won't accidentally belittle someone who does not see the different types right away. Just overall a better impression without that word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost has chosen a notation that is intuitive to someone familiar with redirection on the command line. However, remember that this is C++. The `<` and `>` symbols are still operators; they did not become command-line arguments. The code `bp::std_out > stdout` is an expression. It evaluates to an object of some sort that records where the standard output should go.

---

One trick for adapting to different types is to adjust the point where the condition is made. Instead of conditionally selecting the argument to `operator<` and `operator>`, conditionally select the argument to the `bp::child` constructor:

```
bp::child c(bp::exe("test.exe"),
            in.empty() ? (bp::std_in  < stdin) : (bp::std_in  < in),
            out.empty() ? (bp::std_out > stdout) : (bp::std_out > out));
```

This would be more obvious if it weren't for operator overloading. Even though both `<` symbols in the above look the same, they name different operators because the types of their operands are different. Your situation is essentially needing to call either `f(bp::std_in, stdin)` or `g(bp::std_in, in)`, and there is no way to merge these calls with the ternary operator. It's confusing just because instead of `f` and `g`, the operator names are `<` and `<`.

You might want to use helper variables to make the code easier to read:

```
auto in_stream  =  in.empty() ? (bp::std_in  < stdin)  : (bp::std_in  < in);
auto out_stream = out.empty() ? (bp::std_out > stdout) : (bp::std_out > out);

bp::child c(bp::exe("test.exe"), in_stream, out_stream);
```

Comment: That's fantastic! I didn't realize that `bp::std_in < stdin` actually creates a variable that can be used as a stream for the process. Thank you!

Comment: Though, my compiler seems to fail to compile the code, stating `cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const boost::filesystem::path &'`

Comment: @JackAvante Your `_Ty` looks like a template parameter; if so, the full error message should identify to what `_Ty` resolves, which would be the first step in debugging. It's *probably* a separate issue, though, since my compiler is able to process this code.

Comment: I see now. I tried to replace stdin with bp::close but that seems to not convert correctly. Is there a way to do this with bp::close as well, or similar?.. or can I just use an empty string?

Comment: @JackAvante I'm not sure. If you get the same error with normal use (not using conditionals), you probably have a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the interface being statically typed and variadic.[¹]

In general the various keyword parameters are not guaranteed to be of compatible types, so ternaries like `cond? keyword1 : keyword2` will break down pretty quickly due to type mismatches.

Also, sometimes you will want to dynamically add/remove options.

In my own production code I often opt for traditional control flow and a bit of code duplication, so like

```
if (condition)
    child = bp::child(/* params 1st style */);
else
    child = bp::child(/* params 2nd style */);
```

Of course with many option this leads to combinatoric explosion which is hard to maintain. You can trick it using a more elaborate system of variadic lambdas to combine the keyword arguments.

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline(ios);

bp::group process_group;

bp::async_pipe input(ios);
std::future<std::string> output, error;

if (_working_directory.empty())
    _working_directory = ".";

auto on_exit = [this, &deadline](int exit, std::error_code ec) {
    if (!_command_timed_out) {
        _exit_code = exit;
    }
    deadline.cancel();
    if (ec) log(LOG_WARNING) << "Child process returned " << ec.message();
    else    log(LOG_DEBUG)   << "Child process returned";
};

auto launcher = [](auto&&... args) { return bp::child(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::posix::fd.restrict_inherit()); };

auto redirect_out = [&](auto f) {
    return [&](auto&&... args) {
        if (_discard_output) {
            if (_redirected_output_fd != -1 && !_redirected_output_fname.empty()) {
                log(LOG_ERR) << "Ignoring output redirection with set_discard_output. This is a bug.";
            }
            return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > bp::null, bp::std_err > bp::null);
        }

        if (_redirected_output_fd != -1 && !_redirected_output_fname.empty()) {
            log(LOG_WARNING) << "Conflicting output redirection, ignoring filename with descriptor";
        }

        if (_redirected_output_fd != -1) {
            return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::posix::fd.bind(1, _redirected_output_fd), bp::std_err > error);
        }

        return _redirected_output_fname.empty()
            ? f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > output,                   bp::std_err > error)
            : f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > _redirected_output_fname, bp::std_err > error);
    };
};

bp::environment bp_env = boost::this_process::environment();
for (auto& p : _env)
    bp_env[p.first] = p.second;

auto c = redirect_out(launcher)(_command_path, _args,
        process_group,
        bp::std_in < input,
        bp::start_dir(_working_directory),
        bp_env,
        ios, bp::on_exit(on_exit)
    );

if (_time_constraint) {
    deadline.expires_from_now(*_time_constraint);
    deadline.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code ec) {
        if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            if (ec) {
                log(LOG_WARNING) << "Unexpected condition in CommandRunner deadline: " << ec.message();
            }

            _command_timed_out = true;
            _exit_code = 1;
            ::killpg(process_group.native_handle(), SIGTERM);

            deadline.expires_from_now(3s); // grace time
            deadline.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code ec) { if (!ec) process_group.terminate(); }); // timed out
        }
    });
}

boost::asio::async_write(input, bp::buffer(_stdin_data), [&input](auto ec, auto bytes_written){
    if (ec) {
        log(LOG_WARNING) << "Standard input rejected: " << ec.message() << " after " << bytes_written << " bytes written";
    }
    may_fail([&] { input.close(); });
});

ios.run();

if (output.valid()) _stdout_str = output.get();
if (error.valid())  _stderr_str = error.get();

// make sure no grand children survive
if (process_group && process_group.joinable() && !process_group.wait_for(1s))
    process_group.terminate();
```

Of course you should add exception handling and adapt to your needs.

---

[¹] Don't get me started. To me this is the mistake of  over-engineering. In the presence of the process-exec overhead there is no performance argument to make up for the added complexity and countless bugs [I've seen a few over the years]. There are essential things I don't know how to do with Boost Process.

Of course, the library is still useful so I'll limit my rant :) I felt had some [karma to burn today](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20%5bboost-process%5d%20bp%3a%3achild)

Comment: Great answer, and I completely agree. Honestly, I Boost.Process 0.5 is a little better than the 0.6 version in my opinion, as it allowed a bit more freedom and efficiency.